# How do I Implement Case Validation on a String in Python?

Tags: python, passwords, case-sensitive

I am wondering as to how I can implement case sensitivity verification on a user-entered password. As of this moment, the approval message is displayed, but if a password without both lowercase and uppercase characters is entered, the error message and subsequent re-entry prompt are not displayed. Any ways to fix this?

```
#Password entry
def receivePassword():
    password = input("Enter a password, mane.")
    return password

#Verification of lowercase containment
def lowerCase(password):
    lcase = False
    while lcase ==False:
        for i in password:
            if ord(i) >= 97 and ord(i) <= 122:
                lcase = True
    return lcase

#Verification of uppercase containment
def upperCase(password):
    ucase = False
    while ucase ==False:
        for i in password:
            if ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i) <= 90:
                ucase = True
    return ucase

def validity(lcase,ucase):
    if lcase == True and ucase == True:
        print("That's a nice, valid, password mane.")
    while lcase !=True and ucase!= True:
        print("Re enter a password with upper and lowercase characters.")
        password = input("Enter a password, mane.")

#Top-Level Program
password = receivePassword()
lcase = lowerCase(password)
ucase = upperCase(password)
valid = validity(lcase,ucase)
```

Comment: Please copy here the source code instead of images.

Comment: change "and" to "or" in the validity `while`.